# How do I render a two worded value into the value attribute of an input tag (Express-Handlebars)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I am rendering the handlebars page with the following code

```
router.get("/update", function(req, res) {
  mysql.pool.query("SELECT * FROM workouts WHERE id = ?",[req.query.id], function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))
      for (let data of parsedData) {
        if (data.lbs == 1) {data.lbs = "lbs"}
        else {data.lbs = "kg"}
        let formattedDate = (new Date(data.date)).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        data.date = formattedDate
        data.name = String(data.name)
      }
      let format = {
        input: parsedData
      }
      console.log("FORMAT", format)
      res.render("update", format)
     }
    })
})
```

The format variable has the following data in it

```
FORMAT { input: 
   [ { id: 48,
       name: 'teddy burger',
       reps: 22,
       weight: 45,
       date: '2020-12-08',
       lbs: 'kg' } ] }
```

My handlebars page is below

```
<h1 id="test123">Update This Entry!</h1>
 {{#each input}}
<form class="update-form" name="update" value="update" id="fitness-form">
    <input id="hidden-id" value={{this.id}} hidden>

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name2" type="text" value={{this.name}} required><br>

    <label for="reps">Reps</label>
    <input id="reps2" type="number" value={{this.reps}} required><br>

    <label for="weight">Weight</label>
    <input id="weight2" type="number" value={{this.weight}} required><br>

    <label for="date">Date</label>
    <input id="date2" type="date" value={{this.date}} required><br>

    <label for="unit">Unit</label>
    <input id="unit2" type="text" value={{this.lbs}} placeholder="lbs or kg" required><br>
  
    <input id="submitUpdate" type="submit">
</form>
  {{/each}}
```

When I open the page in the browser though, it seems like anytime I pass in a name that is more than one word, it only grabs the first word and then the second one gets placed outside of the value like in the image below. Any suggestions? Thanks!!
[image]

Comment: If I try putting this.name in like an H1 tag, it prints the entire name. Just doesn't work when I try to set the value of an input tag.

Comment: Use quotes. `value="{{ this.name }}"` Without them, the parser doesn't know that " burger" is part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your value should have quotation marks " and "

```
value="{{this.name}}"
```